# How to declare a class with constructor and child objects?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class called Shapes that contains different shapes(objects), which has a constructor and then i want to add the different objects with their variables. At the end of all i want to display in the console the object's angles.
So i wrote this code but something is missing..any ideas?

```js
class Shapes {
  constructor(){
    var angles = 0;
  }
    Triangle(){
      angles = 3;
      return angles;
}
    Square(){
      angles = 4;
      return angles;
  }
  console.log(Triangle)
}
```

Comment: Hope the MDN docs helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class

Comment: Thank you, CRayen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have completely misunderstood the `class` declaration and its usage. You first need to define a class with name `Shapes` so that the constructor will initialize the `angles` value. Then you can create different shapes(objects) with those angle values.

```js
class Shapes {
  constructor(angles){
    this.angles = angles;
  }
}

var Triangle = new Shapes(3);
console.log(Triangle.angles);

var Square = new Shapes(4);
console.log(Square.angles);
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly! Is there a way to declare a boolean variable in the constructor?

Comment: yes. Pass the value in the parameter and assign using `this` as it is done for `this.angles`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way :

```js
function shapes(angle) {
  this.angles = angle;
}

var Triangle = new shapes(3);
var Square = new shapes(4);

console.log( Triangle.angles );
console.log( Square.angles );
```